# When to assign variables in Protractor?

Tags: jasmine, protractor

As the question says. To be more specific, I am talking about variables which will be used in multiple describe/it blocks in the file.

It seems a lot of my coworkers define our helpers and expectedConditions/other protractor properties globally, before anything.

```
var helper = require('./ourHelper.js');
var expectedConditions = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
```

and then include every other variable within the describe block. I generally just put everything in the root describe. However, I have been told some problems are causes by this when defining someElement.getText() and such.

What is best practice here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What we've done was to use `global` inside `onPrepare()`:

```
onPrepare: function () {
    global.helpers = require("./../helpers/helpers.js");
    global.EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
},
```

Now, in every spec, you can just use globally available `helpers` and `EC` variables.

Comment: What's the advantage of doing this over var helpers = require("./../helpers/helpers.js"); before the describe block?

Comment: @VSO it's cleaner and follows the DRY principle. You'll no longer need to "import" the file each time it's needed. It would be imported once and be available during the test run.

Answer (score 0):

All my page objects extend a basePage, which is where I store any methods or properties used in multiple pages (i.e. helpers). This includes `ExpectedConditions`. If you're not using page objects (maybe this is a good reason to start), you could create a baseSpec instead/in addition to...